# What does 'some to landmarks~' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does ***some to landmarks, some to ordinary buildings***  mean? Does it mean ***(from) some locations to landmarks, (from) some locations to ordinary buildings*** or ***(from) some ordinary buildings to landmarks, (from) some landmarks to ordinary buildings***?

> Spatial reference points are larger than themselves. This isn’t really
> a paradox: landmarks are themselves, but they also define
> neighborhoods around themselves. In a paradigm that has been repeated
> on many campuses, researchers first collect a list of campus landmarks
> from students. Then they ask another group of students to estimate the
> distances between pairs of locations, ***some to landmarks, some to
> ordinary buildings*** on campus. The remarkable finding is that
> distances from an ordinary location to a landmark are judged shorter
> than distances from a landmark to an ordinary location. So, people
> would judge the distance from Pierre’s house to the Eiffel Tower to be
> shorter than the distance from the Eiffel Tower to Pierre’s house.
> Like black holes, landmarks seem to pull ordinary locations toward
> themselves, but ordinary places do not. This asymmetry of distance
> estimates violates the most elementary principles of Euclidean
> distance, that the distance from A to B must be the same as the
> distance from B to A. Judgments of distance, then, are not necessarily
> coherent.

[Mind in Motion: How Action Shapes Thought](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=8ax7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT80&lpg=PT80&dq=Then%20they%20ask%20another%20group%20of%20students%20to%20estimate%20the%20distances%20between%20pairs%20of%20locations,%20some%20to%20landmarks,%20some%20to%20ordinary%20buildings%20on%20campus.&source=bl&ots=-Uo9NWRX_P&sig=ACfU3U3mZy4fVak5wEt1mczhOamwYkGqrQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk4sO1rKrxAhVkKaYKHSbmCrQQ6AEwAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=Then%20they%20ask%20another%20group%20of%20students%20to%20estimate%20the%20distances%20between%20pairs%20of%20locations%2C%20some%20to%20landmarks%2C%20some%20to%20ordinary%20buildings%20on%20campus.&f=false)

Comment: It's not entirely clear.  The sentence by itself implies ***from some unspecified location to certain landmarks; and from some unspecified location to non-landmarks***.  But the example that follows this sentence does not match.  The example suggests ***from a non-landmark to a landmark; and from a landmark to a non-landmark***.   You would have to look at the actual study to see what the students were actually asked to estimate.

Comment: It looks pretty clear to me. The whole *point* of the text is to tell us this "non-intuitive" fact about how people estimate distances. Note that in any given instance of a student being asked to estimate the distance between two points, that distance is apparently always presented as *How far is it from A to B?* And what they're saying is if you ask *How far is it from [ordinary house] to [famous building]?*, then *on average* they guess that distance to be ***shorter*** than *How far is it from [famous building] to [ordinary house]?*, even though obviously the distances are exactly the same.

Comment: @Juhasz is correct; the passage discusses a pair of locations, but the sentence in question does not specify one of the pairs. The result of the study is clear and by virtue of that, what the sentence must mean is also clear, but you can only know that the pairs being contrasted are ord-ord, ord-land, land-ord, and land-land by reading onwards. The sentence itself is vague.